# Storing twodimensional array into single dimensional array

Tags: java

Please help me to fix this. I just want to store a two dimensional array into a single dimensional array is it possible. what I'm trying is that I have to store two dimensional integer array which will be created dynamically.

Comment: i Just declared and initialized the single dimensional integer array  based on the user input after that i created a two dimensional array and i tried to initialized the first item of single dimensional array but i cannot do. it says Type mismatch: cannot convert from int[][] to int.. @Rod_Algonquin

Comment: Go through the help center of SO . It tells you exactly how you should post your Questions here !

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
int[][] arr = new int[Rows][Cols];
int[] arr1D= new int[Rows * Cols];

Rows = arr.length;
if (Rows > 0) {
    Cols = arr[0].length;
} else {
    Cols = 0;
}

for (int row = 0, count = 0; row < Rows; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < Cols; col++) {
        arr1D[count] = arr[row][col];
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What i did wrong here ...public static void main(String[] args) {
  int numberOfArray = 0;
  System.out.println("Enter The Number Of Arrays To be Get:");
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  numberOfArray = scanner.nextInt();
  creatingTwoDimensionalArrays(numberOfArray);
   
 }
 
 public static void creatingTwoDimensionalArrays(int noa){
  twoDiemnsionalArrayGroup = new int[noa];
  for(int iteratorArray = 0;iteratorArray< noa;iteratorArray++){
   twoDiemnsionalArrayGroup[iteratorArray] = new int[2][2];
  }
 }

Comment: @SaravanaKumarChinnaraj:- Its pretty hard to understand the code in comments. Can you edit your question and add your code there?

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Test1 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[][] twoDArrays={{10,5},{4,6},{9,8}};

            ArrayList<Integer> oneDArray= new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i=0; i<twoDArrays.length;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<twoDArrays[i].length;j++){
                    oneDArray.add(twoDArrays[i][j]);
                }
            }//printing onedArray
            for(Integer s:oneDArray){
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }

}
```

Output:

```
10
5
4
6
9
8
```